# Not able to restore, saved Filter data in Ag-grid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I am using AG-GRID version 21.1.0. I have a table on my homepage which loads data on API call. I then applied filter on any number of columns present in my table. Now I am moving to another component using routes. Coming back to my homepage should preserve the filter state for me and after the API call is done, it should show the filtered data on the table as my filter state is already saved when i moved to different component.

I have tried using this.gridApi.getFilterModel() to save the state and this.gridApi.setFilterModel(window.savedModel) to restore the state but it doesn't seems to work

```
watch: {
    data: function(newData, oldData) {
      this.gridApi.setRowData(newData);
      this.rowData = newData;
      this.rows = this.rowData.length;
      this.restoreFilterModel();
    }
  }, 
methods: {
 restoreFilterModel() {
      this.gridApi.setFilterModel(window.savedModel);
      this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
    },
 rowClick(){
      window.savedModel = this.gridApi.getFilterModel();
      routerData.name = "callflow";
}
}`
```

on coming back to my homepage API is been called and the data gets loaded again but i want my filter to persist and show me the filtered data in table.
currently it is showing me complete data what my API is returning.

Comment: Did you try to console window.savedModel after moving different routes ? i think shared state is the best approach to resolve this issue

Comment: yes i did and i was able to get the state saved after routing. Can you share with me any example for shared state?

Comment: simple shared state example - https://codepen.io/braidn/pen/NbGNpE

Comment: I am using store in my project for other requirements but it is for preserving the filter state. With current code also we are able to maintain the filter state. Only issue is that its not able to restore the filter after the page reloads. For restoring we are using below code: please let me know if I am doing something wrong here
      this.gridApi.setFilterModel(window.savedModel);
      this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();

Comment: if you reload page , everything state back to initial state and filter will reset back to orginal state, use localStorage

Comment: something like this - localStorage.setItem("prevFilterState", this.gridApi.getFilterModel()); and use it as  localStorage.getItem("prevFilterState")

Comment: Hope it works :)

Comment: if it works/any issue, let me know

Comment: I could get the expected result by the same approach which i have followed just what i was missing was to code this:   filterParams: {
            defaultOption: "contains",
            clearButton: true,
            newRowsAction: 'keep'  - this you can use if you want to preserve state for any column
          }

Comment: Local storage would also have helped but everytime i am restoring filter i needed the updated records. I think that may not work in local storage but working with my approach

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping on this. :)

Comment: did localstorage approach work??

Comment: i did not tried it with the localstorage

Comment: Did u got the answer for this? @NainaSaxena . I am able to retain the value because i am storing it in backend. But now able to clear